# Why does Altium say this net is uncoupled?

Tags: pcb, altium, differential, routing

I have some differential pairs in Alitum. They require impedance matching to 100R, which is easy enough. Putting the numbers into Saturn PCB Toolkit V7.08, it works out that I want a conductor width of 0.1mm, spacing of 0.4mm to get impedance of around 94 Ohms.

I set the net rule in Altium; min, preferred and max widths all set to 0.1. Min, preferred and max gap set to 0.3, 0.4 and 0.5.

I route the trace using "interactive diff pair route" option in Altium, keeping all the settings to "preferred". I check the nets, and they are 0.1mm wide with a 0.4mm gap between the traces. Yet Altium throws the error "nets are uncoupled for (the full net length)".

I know that gap is quite large (0.4mm) but that is required with the PCB stack up. If that works for the impedance, why would Altium tell me they are uncoupled?

Comment: Is the distance that DRC says they are uncoupled for equal to the total length of the track? I believe in the past I've had trouble with that rule, but only because it would flag things like fanning out the tracks at the end to reach the chip pins they needed to reach.

Comment: @ThePhoton Sorry, I had included that it was for the full net length, but had forgotten stack exchange sees "<" as a formatting character

Comment: Did manual routing fix it

Comment: @MituRaj no, manual routing has same effect as diff pair routing

Comment: How far is it to your nearest reference plane? The traces might each be considered single-ended if they're coupling to a plane instead of to each other.